# Are people who sleep on the left side of the bed happier in their job?

Tags: sleep

According to a [2011 study by hotel chain Premier Inn](https://www.premierinn.com/gb/en/news/2011/so-far-left-its-right.html), people who sleep on the left side are better off than those who sleep on the right side. One of the examples they give:

> In fact, 31% of ‘lefties’ love their job compared with just 18% of ‘righties’

Is there any supporting evidence for this claim?

I don't think this is a case of [illusory superiority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority), which another claim in the article reeks of:

> And two-thirds of those who doze on the left reckon they are calmer than their partner in a crisis.

Comment: Assuming that the stats are true (big assumption) it sounds like an awful lot like a correlation implying causation fallacy http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations